# Append multiple external svg in d3 and bind them with data

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have several svg files that i'd like to include in my d3 chart. I can add them by hard-coding  and use css to properly align them with my chart.

But that seems to be a dumb way. I know I can use d3.xml to import svg from files or copy&paste&append it in the code as an object. But that doesn't solve my problem as there are too many to bind manually.

Is there a way so that I can import and use them in the style of d3's join-update-exit

Comment: This question leaves too much to the imagination in its current form. Code samples are best. Some questions are: are the svg files http accessible? What alignment needs to be done? What is the content of these svg files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/explunit/5988971). Instead of using *d3.xml*, add inline svg inside  and *use* them later.

```
.append("use")
.attr("xlink:href",function(d){return "#mySymbol"+d})
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5vt88x/20/)